Tosca parser issue with snakeyaml upgrade to 2.x from 1.31
I am facing issue with parsing of my csar file using Tosca after upgrading snakeyaml version to 2.x,I tried to extract my csar file but could not find anything that can cause issue.
below attached is the error log:-
8:18:57.074 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] || INFO 
        org.onap.so.asdc.installer.ToscaResourceStructure - ASDC_RECEIVE_SERVICE_NOTIF ***PATH ASDC /tmp/junit6483597170737715345/ASDC/10/service_Vmme59PortMirrorSvc_csar__2_.csar
08:18:57.341 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] || DEBUG
        org.onap.so.asdc.installer.ToscaResourceStructure - null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.onap.sdc.toscaparser.api.prereq.CSAR._validateExternalReferences(CSAR.java:333)
    at org.onap.sdc.toscaparser.api.prereq.CSAR.validate(CSAR.java:101)
    at org.onap.sdc.toscaparser.api.ToscaTemplate._getPath(ToscaTemplate.java:712)
    at org.onap.sdc.toscaparser.api.ToscaTemplate.init(ToscaTemplate.java:159)
    at org.onap.sdc.toscaparser.api.ToscaTemplate.<init>(ToscaTemplate.java:120)
    at org.onap.sdc.tosca.parser.impl.SdcToscaParserFactory.init(SdcToscaParserFactory.java:100)
    at org.onap.sdc.tosca.parser.impl.SdcToscaParserFactory.getSdcCsarHelper(SdcToscaParserFactory.java:93)
    at org.onap.so.asdc.installer.ToscaResourceStructure.updateResourceStructure(ToscaResourceStructure.java:148)
    at org.onap.so.asdc.client.ASDCController.processCsarServiceArtifacts(ASDCController.java:898)
    at com.att.ecomp.mso.asdc.client.ATTASDCController.processResourceNotification(ATTASDCController.java:60)
    at org.onap.so.asdc.client.ASDCController.treatNotification(ASDCController.java:631)
    at org.onap.so.asdc.client.test.rest.ASDCRestInterface.invokeASDCService(ASDCRestInterface.java:100)
    at org.onap.so.asdc.client.test.rest.ASDCRestInterface$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$17b5ea94.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:792)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:762)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:762)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:707)
    at org.onap.so.asdc.client.test.rest.ASDCRestInterface$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bdbf0092.invokeASDCService(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:475)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:397)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:684)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.serviceImpl(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:502)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

My code:-
public void updateResourceStructure(IArtifactInfo artifact) throws ASDCDownloadException {

        try {
            SdcToscaParserFactory factory = SdcToscaParserFactory.getInstance();// Autoclosable

            String filePath =
                    Paths.get(msoConfigPath, "ASDC", artifact.getArtifactVersion(), artifact.getArtifactName())
                            .normalize().toString();

            File spoolFile = new File(filePath);

            logger.debug("ASDC File path is: {}", spoolFile.getAbsolutePath());
            logger.info(LoggingAnchor.FOUR, MessageEnum.ASDC_RECEIVE_SERVICE_NOTIF.toString(), "***PATH", "ASDC",
                    spoolFile.getAbsolutePath());

            **sdcCsarHelper = factory.getSdcCsarHelper(spoolFile.getAbsolutePath(), false);**

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug(e.getMessage(), e);
            logger.error(LoggingAnchor.SIX, MessageEnum.ASDC_GENERAL_EXCEPTION_ARG.toString(),
                    "Exception caught during parser *****LOOK********* " + artifact.getArtifactName(), "ASDC",
                    "processResourceNotification", ErrorCode.BusinessProcessError.getValue(),
                    "Exception in " + "processResourceNotification", e);

            throw new ASDCDownloadException("Exception caught when passing the csar file to the parser ", e);
        }

        serviceMetadata = sdcCsarHelper.getServiceMetadata();

    }

The line marked in bold actually breaks,please help.
If I downgrade to 1.3x version it works fine.
